# Scrape data in python from yahoo finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I want to scrape data from yahoo finance for a specific symbol.

I can scrape the table format but I can't scrape non-table format. I applied the same principle to scrape information in the same page, but no result.

So far I could scrape from `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL`

The code I use to scrape table is :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import requests
import lxml
from lxml import html

symbol = 'AAPL'

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/profile?p=' + symbol

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

table = tree.xpath('//table') 

assert len(table) == 1 
tstring = lxml.etree.tostring(table[0], method='html')
df = pd.read_html(tstring)[0]

df
```

I want to scrape the table on the right

```
Sector: Consumer Goods
Industry: Electronic Equipment
Full Time Employees: 137,000
```

I would appreciate if you could help to get the information or give some tips and advice.

Comment: Why do you leave out your imports?  Kind of important for reproduction.

Comment: There already exists a yahoo finance library, by the way

Comment: If you want to scrape webpages, beautifulsoup is probably better than plain XPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [following-sibling](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

```
import requests
from lxml import html

xp = "//span[text()='Sector']/following-sibling::span[1]"

symbol = 'AAPL'

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/profile?p=' + symbol

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

d = {}
for label in ['Sector', 'Industry', 'Full Time Employees']:
    xp = f"//span[text()='{label}']/following-sibling::span[1]"
    s = tree.xpath(xp)[0]
    d[label] = s.text_content()


print(d['Full Time Employees'])
print(d['Industry'])
print(d['Sector'])
```

Comment: If I print(s.text_content()) it gives the number of 'Full Time Employees', so how I can get the value of others: 'Sector', 'Industry'? it is a bit unclear.

Comment: This [demo](https://repl.it/repls/BustlingHumbleScans) outputs `Sector Technology` then `Industry Consumer Electronics` then `Full Time Employees 137,000` so I do not know what you are missing.

Comment: It does not work sustainably. the print gives only output of number of employees

Comment: It seems you lack some of the basics. Perhaps you need to go through some of the tutorials? I've edited my answer to show how you can access individual values.

Comment: actually I indicated above that I only can scrap table so that is why I ask here and everyone else.

Comment: I suggest you go through the [Beginners Guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) and the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)